# awk max value of column two for dates in column one

Tags: linux, sorting, awk

I am trying to print only max values of column two for dates in column one.

My file is:

```
2014-04-09,135303
2014-04-09,416400
2014-04-15,143684
2014-04-15,156011
2014-04-15,184406
2014-04-16,1123083
2014-04-16,167486
2014-04-16,862196
2014-04-17,963023
2014-04-19,583844
```

Required Output:

```
2014-04-09,416400
2014-04-15,184406
2014-04-16,1123083
2014-04-17,963023
2014-04-19,583844
```

I tried sort but not working:

```
cat file|sort -k2 -r | sort --unique --stable -k1
```

please suggest how it can be done using awk or sort

Answer (score 1):

```
kent$  awk -F, '{a[$1]=$2>a[$1]?$2:a[$1]}END{for(x in a)print x "," a[x]}' file
2014-04-15,184406
2014-04-16,1123083
2014-04-17,963023
2014-04-09,416400
2014-04-19,583844
```

if you want the result ordered by date, pipe the line above to `sort`:

```
awk -F, '{a[$1]=$2>a[$1]?$2:a[$1]}END{for(x in a)print x "," a[x]}' f|sort 
2014-04-09,416400
2014-04-15,184406
2014-04-16,1123083
2014-04-17,963023
2014-04-19,583844
```